# How do I vectorize this loop in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array:

```
arr = np.array([3, 7, 4])
```

And these boolean indices:

```
cond = np.array([False, True, True])
```

I want to find the index of the maximum value in the array where the boolean condition is true.  So I do:

```
np.ma.array(arr, mask=~cond).argmax()
```

Which works and returns 1.  But if I had an array of boolean indices:

```
cond = np.array([[False, True, True], [True, False, True]])
```

Is there a vectorized/numpy way of iterating through the array of boolean indices to return [1, 2]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your special use case of `argmax`, you may use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and set the masked values to negative infinity:

```
>>> inf = np.iinfo('i8').max
>>> np.where(cond, arr, -inf).argmax(axis=1)
array([1, 2])
```

alternatively, you can manually broadcast using [`np.tile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
>>> np.ma.array(np.tile(arr, 2).reshape(2, 3), mask=~cond).argmax(axis=1)
array([1, 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want a vectorized version of:

```
In [302]: [np.ma.array(arr,mask=~c).argmax() for c in cond]
Out[302]: [1, 2]
```

What are the realistic dimensions of `cond`?  If the number of rows is small compared to the columns (or length of `arr`) an iteration like this is probably not expensive.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31767220/901925 use of `tile` looks good.  Here I change it slightly:

```
In [308]: np.ma.array(np.tile(arr,(cond.shape[0],1)),mask=~cond).argmax(axis=1)
Out[308]: array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

As expected, the list comprehension times scale with the rows of `cond`, while the tiling approach is just a bit slower than a single row case.  But with times around `92.7 µs` this masked array approach is much slower than `arr.argmax()`.  Masking adds a lot of overhead.

The `where` version is quite a bit faster

```
np.where(cond, arr, -100).argmax(1)  # 20 µs
```

A deleted answer suggested

```
(arr*cond).argmax(1)   # 8 µs
```

which is even faster.   As proposed it didn't work if there are negative `arr` values.  But it can probably be adjusted to handle those.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.array([3, 7, 4])

cond = np.array([[False, True, True], [True, False, True]])


def multi_slice_max(bool_arr , x ):
    return np.ma.array(x, mask=~bool_arr).argmax()

np.apply_along_axis(multi_slice_max , 1 , cond , arr)
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` does an iteration under the covers.  So I don't expect any speed advantage.